# Manipulação de campos vazios

Tags: sql, sql-server

Nessa consulta, eu tenho algumas lojas que não tem venda identificada. Trazendo o resultado como nulo. Isso impacta No campo de porcentagem e de total.
Como eu poderia fazer para que os campos null sejam interpretados como 0 e eu possa fazer os cálculos da minha query?

```
  select ti.Loja as Loja,ti.NomeLoja  as 'Nome Loja', ti.QtdTransacaoIdent as 
   'Identificado', 
    tni.QtdTransacaoNaoIdent as 'Não Identificado',
   SUM(QtdTransacaoIdent)+ SUM(QtdTransacaoNaoIdent)as Total,   
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),
   cast(QtdTransacaoIdent as money)/cast(QtdTransacaoIdent+ QtdTransacaoNaoIdent as money)*100)+' %' AS '% Engajamento'   
   from #temp_ident ti
   left join #temp_n_ident tni on tni.loja = ti.loja
   group by ti.Loja,ti.NomeLoja, ti.QtdTransacaoIdent,tni.QtdTransacaoNaoIdent
   order by Loja, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(50),
   cast(QtdTransacaoIdent as money)/cast(QtdTransacaoIdent+ QtdTransacaoNaoIdent as money)*100) 
   desc
```

Comment: Utilize a função COALESCE para considerar zero aonde você tenha NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para substituir o campo NULL por um valor, utilize o ISNULL().

```
SELECT ISNULL(name, 'Não Encontrado') FROM bairros;
```

> Retorna 'Não encontrado' se o name é NULL :)

Mais informações sobre esta função, acesse a documentação oficial:
[Documentação Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql)

Espero ter ajudado..

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, eu acabei não pensando nessa função, is null. Ela resolveu meu problema da seguinte forma.

Se uma das lojas não tiver venda identificada ou não identificada, o  total vendido no dia, será o valor da outra loja, como por exemplo:

Loja   NomeLoja     Venda Identificada   Venda NaoIdentificada   Total Engajamento
209   Extra Jundiai.   73                         0                                73    NULL

Agora vou ajustar isso para o calculo de porcentagem.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado.